# What is a simple way to take a specific array value in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to take a specific value in an array named `lista` in the format `[x,y]`. But, I only want the `x` values in the array.

In `JavaScript`, I would just do this `lista.map(l => l[0])`. 
Now what is a simple way to do this in `Python` ?

Comment: Include sample inputs and your desired output, as well as what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension:

```
[l[0] for l in lista]
```

And to get the `y` value you'd use `l[1]` instead of `l[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the items of `lista` with a list comprehension like this:

```
[x for x, _ in lista]
```

Comment: Now if I want the y value; would it be [y for y, _ in lista].

Comment: No, that'd be `[y for _, y in lista]` instead.

Comment: @Anonymous Of course not, that's exactly the same. It should be `_, y`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `map` and `lambda`:

```
list(map(lambda elem: elem[0], lista))
```

If you wish to retrieve the second element, change `elem[0]` to `elem[1]`.